# DLIB : Training Shape_predictor for 194 landmarks (helen dataset)

Tags: c++, feature-detection, training-data, dlib

I am training **DLIB**'s **shape_predictor** for 194 face landmarks using **helen dataset** which is used to detect face landmarks through `face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp` of dlib library.

Now it gave me an `sp.dat` binary file of around **45 MB** which is less compared to file given (http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/v18.10/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) for 68 face landmarks. In training

- Mean training error : 0.0203811
- Mean testing error  : 0.0204511

and when I used trained data to get face landmarks position, IN result I got..

[image]

which are very deviated from the result got from 68 landmarks

68 landmark image:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Edited link, and added image.

Comment: I assume your question is - *why?*

Comment: What parameters did you train the set with? If I recall there are settings that will make it train for a lot longer and harder...

Comment: @LamarLatrell I am training with 300 images for training and 20 images for testing and I have prepared `training_with_face_landmarks.xml` and `testing_with_face_landmarks.xml` file in which each image's position having one face with 194 landmarks is specified.

Comment: @NAYA, Could you share your 194 Points Database? Is there a reference for 194 points database? Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, looks like you haven't read the [code](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html) comments (?):

```
shape_predictor_trainer trainer;
// This algorithm has a bunch of parameters you can mess with.  The
// documentation for the shape_predictor_trainer explains all of them.
// You should also read Kazemi's paper which explains all the parameters
// in great detail.  However, here I'm just setting three of them
// differently than their default values.  I'm doing this because we
// have a very small dataset.  In particular, setting the oversampling
// to a high amount (300) effectively boosts the training set size, so
// that helps this example.
trainer.set_oversampling_amount(300);
// I'm also reducing the capacity of the model by explicitly increasing
// the regularization (making nu smaller) and by using trees with
// smaller depths.  
trainer.set_nu(0.05);
trainer.set_tree_depth(2);
```

Have a look at the [Kazemi paper](http://www.csc.kth.se/~vahidk/papers/KazemiCVPR14.pdf), ctrl-f the string 'parameter' and have a read...

Comment: I increased the parameters value but now it is showing an run time error bad allocation , which means new operator is unable to allocate memory for new variables. does bigger tree depth requires more memory.

Comment: Hello! Can you say exactly what parameters I should to use to improve accuracy? Because I already trained a several predictors with different parameters(nu, tree_depth, cascade_depth) and I get almost the same results(I get results like TS results). Any additional help will be useful!