# DLIB: train_shape_predictor_ex.exe for 194 landmarks with halen dataset gives runtime error: bad allocation

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, bad-alloc, dlib

I am trying train dlib's shape_predictor for 194 landmarks with [halen](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~vuongle2/helen/) dataset

but it gives bad allocation exception when I run it command prompt

```
D:\Facial Feature Extraction>train_shape_predictor_ex.exe face_detector
Program is started
exception thrown!
bad allocation
```

, I reduced the number of image to only 50 then it run successfully but the result is not satisfactory. So I tried to train with 64 GB RAM System but bow I increased the parameter

```
trainer.set_nu(0.05);
trainer.set_tree_depth(2);
```

but now it is still showing bad allocation error. If I train with less data and for smaller parameter the [train model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908402/dlib-training-shape-predictor-for-194-landmarks-helen-dataset) is not correct.

Comment: Yes, Dlib's shape predictor takes a lot of RAM and CPU time (one core) for training. trainer.set_tree_depth(2); - this param increases RAM requirement exponentional, num_cascades and some other - linear.  Can you tell me all your training params, amount of images and how many RAM does it takes when it does not have an error?

Comment: @Evgeniy When there is no error: `1,934 GB` RAM,  and number of images-372 as training samples and 52 as testing samples. Parameters values is same as given in [link](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html)

Comment: are you sore that your code is 64 bit?

Comment: @Evgeniy Are you asking about operating system?

Comment: @Evgeniy No My code is 32 bit (it showed in task Manager)

Comment: so, this is the reason. recompile to 64 bit and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your application in Release Mode and target to 64-bit Windows plateform.

- Also Enable \LARGEADDRESSAWARE Flag in your Project.

Here is a link to your question:
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413998/why-my-program-does-not-take-more-than-2-gb-ram-on-64-gb-ram-system/37695690#37695690)