# Why my program does not take more than 2 GB RAM on 64 GB RAM System?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory, dlib

I am trying to train a [Dlib's train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html) with [Halen](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~vuongle2/helen/) dataset. I compiled the code with Visual Studio in `release mode` for `64-bit plateform` as `console application`.

When I run `the train_shape_predictor_ex.exe` in command prompt, the executed process started and I saw in `Task Manager` that memory consumption by this process was increasing but it was stopped till around **1.9 GB**  and gave a Run-time Exception: **bad allocation**. It is unable to take more RAM than around around 1.9 GB RAM even My system is **64 GB RAM**

Can anybody help me getting solve this problem?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Because this is the maximum allowed for a single application. Your question I think is off topic but did you research it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891593/the-maximum-amount-of-memory-any-single-process-on-windows-can-address

Comment: @FirstStep What do you mean by single application. I have seen in my task Manager that a MySQL application process was using about 16 GB of Physical Memory of total(64 GB) RAM

Comment: @FirstStep Are you sure? I swear Firefox was sitting at 8.3GB of RAM when I closed it the other day (yes I have a *lot* of tabs)

Comment: @bor I attached a reference

Comment: You must have built a 32 bit application.

Comment: Are you sure you've got more than 2.1 GB free RAM?

Comment: @drescherjm No ! I have chosen 64 bit option and release mode in Visual Studio to build the application.

Comment: @ForceBru No sorry for mistake.. I didn't get more than **2 GB** or hardly **1.9 GB**

Comment: Please  get your values set and stop editing your OP like crazy

Comment: Maybe your allocation is actually bad. I mean if you try to allocate 50TB of memory it will fail.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is you are using a 32 bit int to calculate the size of the allocation  (and this is wrapping around to negative values because of overflow). Remember that even in 64 bit mode with Visual Studio `int` is 32 bits.

Comment: BTW, There is nothing special you need to do on windows to allocate over 2GB of memory on a 64 bit native `c++` application. I have been allocating > 2GB in my 64 bit Visual Studio compiled applications for over a decade.

Comment: @drescherjm I throught  to increase the pagefile size upto 20 GB but it didn't work out. Can you tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Please use a debugger, and inspect the line of code causing your error.  "unable to take more ram" is not how to request help for a c++ coding issue.  See [MCVE].

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Thanks for suggestion. I will work on that.

Comment: Did you accidentally remove the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag from your application? Without that flag, you get only 2GB of address space.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am not aware of it. It might happened. I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build C++ Application which can consume Physical memory than normal 32-Bit application(means 2GB), It is needed to built the application in 64-bit mode.

- Enable the  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag to true
- Build application for 65-bit target CPU.

Comment: Am I not aware of something or should that be "64-bit" instead of "65-bit"?