# Dlib Shape Predictor

Tags: face-detection, dlib

The default dlib shape predictor (which predicts 68 landmark points on face) is the model namely "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2" which is trained on relatively smaller dataset.
I wonder if someone has trained the model with a larger dataset and has made the model publicly available?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing off-the-shelf. Also keep in mind that the 68-point dataset has a non-commercial license, so you might have to create your own model anyway.

The Helen dataset might be a good alternative. Somebody was working on a dlib predictor for that: [DLIB : Training Shape_predictor for 194 landmarks (helen dataset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908402/dlib-training-shape-predictor-for-194-landmarks-helen-dataset)